# Deserialize arbitrary JSON keys and raw values

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Using JSON.Net I want to deserialize a JSON object that looks something like this:

```
"properties": {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "Fred",
    "baz": [694481.61, 693638.0, 692624.65, 692354.54]
}
```

and end up with a `dictionary<string,string>` that looks like this:

```
{ "foo", "1" },
{ "bar", "\"Fred\"" },
{ "baz", "[694481.61, 693638.0, 692624.65, 692354.54]" }
```

The key points to note are:

1. The keys are not known in advance. (Hence the use of a dictionary rather than deserializing to a class with predefined properties foo, bar and baz.)
2. The **value strings in the dictionary** are the **raw JSON text from the JSON stream**. So strings include their encapsulating quotation marks, and arrays include their encapsulating square brackets.

**What I have tried so far**

1. Parse the values as `JRaw` objects. This would work if I knew the key names in advance: I could declare matching properties in my class as type `JRaw` - e.g. `public JRaw foo { get; set; }`. But the key names are not predefined so I can't.
2. Create a `RawValueDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter` custom converter that takes the stream and deserializes it directly to a `dictionary<string,string>`. I thought this would be straightforward, but the raw text of the original stream is not available inside `ReadJson()`; the stream has already been tokenized and `ReadJson()` only receives the interpreted token and token type.
3. Write my own tokenizer and forget about using Json.NET. It may come to this but I don't want to 'reinvent the wheel.'

Comment: Deserialise to `Dictionary<string, object>` instead

Comment: So you want them as strings? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: You state that the values are JSON, not that you want to decode them as strings.

Comment: OK, I've clarified 'values' as 'value strings in the dictionary'. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deserialise to `Dictionary<string, JRaw>` which gets you half way there. For example:

```
//Example class
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, JRaw> properties { get; set; }
}

var json = "<from the question>";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

foreach (var property in result.Properties)
{
    var value = property.Value.ToString();
}
```

If you still want the values as strings, you can convert like this:

```
var stringDictionary = result.Properties.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.ToString());
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'm not sure why that solution had eluded me for so long. Just a pity I need to copy the `<string,JRaw>` dictionary to a `<string,string>` one but never mind. Thanks.

Comment: Well you could write a custom converter to avoid that step, it's not too difficult really, but if this solution works, then why bother :)

Comment: That was my original approach, but I couldn't figure out how to persuade `ReadJson()` to receive a `JRaw` type rather than a `JValue` interpreted token.